# Get a Vector of Strings from a Rc<RefCell<Vec<String>>> in Rust

Tags: rust

I have a function that takes in a `Vec<String>` value. I want to use this function on values contained inside `my_ref`, so I need to extract a `Vec<String>` out of a `Rc<RefCell<Vec<String>>>`.

I thought I could do this by dereferencing a borrow of my `my_ref`, just like I would for a `Rc<RefCell<f32>>>` or `Rc<RefCell<i32>>>` value:

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

fn main() {
    let my_ref = Rc::from(RefCell::from(vec![
        "Hello 1".to_string(),
        "Hello 2".to_string(),
    ]));
    let my_strings: Vec<String> = *my_ref.borrow();
    let count = count_strings(my_strings);
}

fn count_strings(strings: Vec<String>) -> usize {
    strings.len()
}
```

But doing so results in a dereferencing error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of dereference of `Ref<'_, Vec<String>>`
cannot move out of dereference of `Ref<'_, Vec<String>>`
move occurs because value has type `Vec<String>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

So then, how do I properly extract a `Vec<String>` from a `Rc<RefCell<Vec<String>>>`?

Comment: Why would `count_strings` take `strings: Vec<String>` instead of `strings: &[String]` or something even more generic, since requiring `String` is also pretty heavy. This is only a problem because `count_strings` explicitly says it needs to own a whole vector with strings, which is not at all needed it looks like.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-to-a-string-string-vec-vec-o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RefCell::borrow` returns a reference, not an owned value, that's why you having such an error. I can name two different solution for that problem.

#### Promoting `Rc` to exclusively-owned type

`Rc::try_unwrap` is able to check, whether there's other references to the data. If it's the only one, it can be safely converted to the inner type. Then, an owned `RefCell` can be converted into its inner via `into_inner` function.

```rust
let my_ref = Rc::from(RefCell::new(vec![..]));
let inner: Vec<_> = Rc::try_unwrap(my_ref).expect("I hereby claim that my_ref is exclusively owned").into_inner();
```

#### Replacing inner value

If for some reason you want to grab inner value that is already referenced, you may consider replacing it. Note, that you need to create a appropriate value for the type (i.e. with `trait Default`). Here's the example:

```rust
let my_ref = Rc::from(RefCell::new(vec![..]));
let inner: Vec<_> = my_ref.borrow_mut().take();
// or
let inner: Vec<_> = my_ref.borrow_mut().replace(vec![]);
```